# Flex loitering objects with 0 paths

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, flex4, profiling

My application is leaking a visual component called GraphViewer. Every time the user changes graphs a new viewer is created and the old one is removed from the stage and discarded. Yet memory seems to leak. When I use the Flex profiler to track loitering objects it shows that GraphViewer instances indeed leak, but when I examine the object references of the loitering viewers I see that all of them (except one) have 0 paths to GC root.

I take a memory snapshot after GC and then change the graph (create a new viewer) N times. Then I do GC, take another snapshot and look at loitering objects. I see N GraphViewer objects loitering, but N-1 of them actually have 0 paths and only one has anything actually referencing it.

Why is the Flex profiler showing objects as loitering when they cannot be reached from the GC root? Is the Flex profiler reliable?

Answer (score 2):

First off, why do you need to create a new instance of your component when new data arrives?  Seems a bit wasteful.  It's better to reuse an instance than to create a new one.

Second, it's hard to answer your issue without code, but often times the reason why a view component is kept in memory is because someone either still have a reference to it or an event listener hasn't been cleaned properly.

And lastly, there has been a known bug in the GC for some time now (though I haven't tested it recently; been about a year since I could reproduce) where large memory 'islands' (think of a very large module) won't clean up properly because the round trip algorithm for the GC won't figure that it's disconnected from the rest.  To alleviate that, you might want to implement an IDisposable interface where your 'parent' view calls a destroy function before removing from stage (which then propagates throughout the component and it's children to destroy as well).

Good luck.

Comment: To reiterate and focus on part of J_A_X's answer, check your event listeners.  For every instance you addEventListener to, ensure that removeEventListener is called prior to destroying an object.  In my projects, this tends to be the most common source of leaks.

Comment: The situation I described is a simplification of the actual project. It's a very complex UI with hundreds of recursive components. Didn't want to get into that here. But the bottom line is I'm actually using the Remove event to clean up the references to these objects whenever the model changes. If it's a GC bug then I guess I don't have a choice but to reuse instances. But doing manual releasing of all references in the project is just insanely error prone and can't be the answer... (what the heck is GC for, right?). So I'm just wondering if anyone's encountered this 0 paths phenomenon.

Comment: Also, finding all addEventListeners and making sure removeEventListener is called for each one, even if the items are not referenced, won't solve the problem for all those mxml based listeners (or are you suggesting that I somehow release those too)? I just refuse to believe the Flash GC is so terrible.. :)

Comment: GC is for cleaning up, but it can't clean up bad development.  Why would you be create a new instance every time anyways?  It's wasteful and useless, especially if you're component is heavy (which is sounds like it is).  Seems to me that your problem is faulty architecture/code more than just 'Let the GC handle it'.  There's no GC out there that is foolproof.

Comment: MXML based listeners are cleaned up automatically after removal from stage.  Again, I've never seen a problem with that particular problem.  If anything, it's a problem with your code.