# Flex profiler shows object with 0 references

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling, flash-builder

I used great Adobe profiler to tune app, and found strange object that has no references but stays in memory. Profilers says that object has Paths=0 when I try to expand item. So question is: why object is kept is memory, while there is no references to it?
[image: Screenshot of profiler]

I pressed GC button and made window resize (more powerful forcing of GC).
Env: Flash Builder 4.5 (sdk 3.6).

Comment: What's the Great Adobe Profiler? Sounds like a Hero of some police game...

Comment: and when you pressed the button. Whats happend. What is your question?

Comment: Don't ask  your question through google translate.  We don't understand the question and there's very little information here.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was middle night when I wrote question. I also found similar question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142993/flex-loitering-objects-with-0-paths